# Excel function that counts hours doesnt work

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was trying to make a function, that sums the amount of hours between two hours, and takes of amount of hours from other cells.

I've tried refering multiple guides  but without any luck

```
=TEXT((B5-C5)-(E5-D5);"hh:mm")
```

The expected result is that the output will show amount of hours and minutes that adds and deducts hours from multiple cells, that are in the formula. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Do the cells contain an hour as a number, or a value formatted as a time in hours and minutes? Can you provide an example with expected inputs and output? Plz see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, all cells are formatted as hh:mm, see

[image]

If you go past midnight you have to alter the calculation, but as you don't show any data this is just a simple example.